# "Don't Repeat Yourself" approach to a jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, dry, color-picker

I have a form with several inputs. When these inputs are clicked, a color picker addon for jquery (farbtastic) is loaded within a fade in/out dropdown.

Each input is unique and will load a different color picker each time. The code I'm using for this is:

```
// Color Picker Popup Menus
$('html, #mgBgColor, input').click(function() { 
    $('#picker-mgBgColor').fadeOut('fast'); 
});

$('#mgBgColor, #picker-mgBgColor').click(function(e){ 
    if(!$('#picker-mgBgColor').is(":visible")) { 
        $('#picker-mgBgColor').stop().fadeIn('fast'); 
    }
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

`#mgBgColor` is the ID of the specific input field.

`#picker-mgBgColor` is the ID that calls the color picker

The HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="bg">BG color:</label>
    <input type="input" id="mgBgColor" name="bg" value="" />    
    <span id="picker-mgBgColor"></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="textcolor">Text color:</label>
    <input type="input" id="mgTextColor" name="textcolor" value="" />
    <span id="picker-mgTextColor"></span>   
</p>
```

My problem is that I'm repeating this big chunk of code for several different input fields. **How can I code just one dropdown menu that works for all of the color picker id's ?**

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of that ^ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add classes to each type of element to group them together:

```
               <p>
                    <label for="bg">BG color:</label>
                    <input class="input-class" type="input" id="mgBgColor" name="bg" value="" />    
                    <span class="picker" id="picker-mgBgColor"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="textcolor">Text color:</label>
                    <input class="input-class" type="input" id="mgTextColor" name="textcolor" value="" />
                    <span class="picker" id="picker-mgTextColor"></span>   
                </p>
```

Then you can target the elements by these classes:

```
$('html, .input-class, input').click(function() { 
    $('.picker').fadeOut('fast'); 
});

$('.input-class').click(function(e){ 
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) { 
        $(this).next().stop().fadeIn('fast'); 
    }
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

$('.picker').click(function(e){ 
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/xW2g6/

Comment: Works great. Simple as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used farbtastic, but the general way to do this is to use classes rather than IDs. You would have some sort of re-usable class `"colorPickable"` or whatever you want to call it. Then you will traverse the DOM to limit yourself to the particular set of elements you want to effect.

The API for DOM traversal is pretty rich, but the shortlist of methods to look up would include `.siblings()`, '`.closest()`, `.parent()`, `.next()`, `.prev()`, `.children()`, and `.find()`. You won't need'em all, but without sample code of your structure, it's hard to say.

[update: I see the sample HTML is now included, but other people are already onboard with specific code examples so I'll leave them to it... though I think there's a misunderstanding of what your needs are]

Answer (score 0):

Use a function

```
function ConfigurePicker(picker) {    
    $('html, #mgBgColor, input').click(function() { 
        picker.fadeOut('fast'); 
    });

    picker.click(function(e){ 
        if(!picker.is(":visible")) { 
            picker.stop().fadeIn('fast'); 
        }
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
var picker = $('#mgBgColor, #picker-mgBgColor');
ConfigurePicker(picker);
```

This way you are DRY and you don't execute the same selector so many times, which you should also try and avoid.